# VBA nested loops exiting early

Tags: excel, nested-loops, vba

I have a vba script which is supposed to copy data from one sheet to another. It does by means of three nested for loops. Stepping through the code in debugging these appear to work perfectly, but when the vba script is run they appear to stop too early. Otherwise the vba script works.

I have been staring at this for hours and cannot for the life of me see what would cause the loops to stop early. I'm hoping the solution is something simple I've missed, but I am at a genuine loss, not for the first time since I started this.

The sheet is organised as follows:

Sheet1, contains the data to be copied.

- Each row contains a seperate response, of which there are 55 in the test data
- The sheet contains nine blocks of data, named Episode 1-9. Each episode contains column where an integer represent a start, end and interval time.
- In the test data each episode is identical except for the start/end times.
- The maximum value for EndTime is 36
- The test data is over the first four Episode blocks only, so Episode4 contains EndTime=36 for each row

Sheet2, where the data is to go
-First column contains each RespondentID copied over 36 rows
-Second column contains numbers 1-36, thus representing that time slot for that respondent
-11 Columns after that contain the area where the data copied from sheet1 for that Respondent/Time is put. These 36x11 areas are named "Response1-55" in the test data

The logic of the vba script is as follows:

Counters: 
- n counter for number of respondents
- r counter for number of episodes
- i counter for rows within the responses being copied to.

->For each response (starting with n=1 to Respondents)
--> Select the first episode (Starting with r=1 to 9)
     --->For each episode
     --->Read the start, end and interval times
     --->Starting from i = Start to i=End copy the relevant cells from the n'th row of the r'th episode
     --->Copy those cells to the i'th row of the current response on sheet2
     --->When you reach the EndTime of the current episode, go to the next one (next r)
-->If the episode you just finished has 36 as its EndTime then go to the next response, or continue till you run out of episodes.
->Next Response

In debugging the code appears to do exactly this.

However when I run the vba script on the test sheet it works only for episodes 1 and 2. The data from episodes 3 and 4 is not copied. Nothing is copied in its place, and the data which IS copied is correct in every respect. There are no error messages at any point.

If anyone could suggest why this might be happening I would build unto them an actual church. The answer could also be added here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119323/nested-for-loops-in-different-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594693/vba-copy-from-a-union-of-two-ranges-to-a-row-of-another-range) Which does not yet have a section for VBA.

A link to the test sheet is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41041934/MrExcelExample/TornHairExampleSheet.xlsm

The relevant part of the code is here

```
Sub PopulateMedia()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Count the total number of response rows in original sheet
    Dim Responses As Long, n As Integer, i As Integer, r As Integer
        Responses = (Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3) ' equals 55 in test sheet

    'For each response...
    For n = 1 To Responses
        i = 1 'Reset i for new response
            Dim curr_resp As Range
                Set curr_resp = Sheets(2).Range("Response" & n) 'Define a range containing all response data

            For r = 1 To 9  'For each episode...
                Dim curr_ep As Range 'Define a range containing episode data for all responses
                    Set curr_ep = Sheets(1).Range("episode" & r)

                Dim Stime As Integer, Etime As Integer, Itime As Integer 'Variables contain start, end and inter-episode times
                    Stime = curr_ep.Cells(n, 1)
                    Etime = curr_ep.Cells(n, 17)
                    Itime = curr_ep.Cells(n, 19)

                    For i = Stime To (Etime + Itime) 'for each time-slot...
                        If i <= Etime Then
                          Dim a As Variant
                            a = curr_ep.Range(curr_ep.Cells(n - 3, 1), curr_ep.Cells(n - 3, 11))
                            curr_resp.Rows(i) = a 'Copy data from above current episode to current response for slots between Stime and Etime
                        End If
                    Next i
                If Etime = 36 Then Exit For
             Next r
     Next n

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To disclose, I have already had help on this project from this site, [VBA copy from a union of two ranges to a row of another range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594693/vba-copy-from-a-union-of-two-ranges-to-a-row-of-another-range) but the code has been changed slightly since then and this is a different problem.

Once more, thank you enormously for any help which might come of this. I have been staring at this for hours and do not see where the error is. Any guidance at all greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to reconsider the whole design of the spreadsheet at some stage - using named ranges the way you do it is error prone and difficult to debug (as you have noticed!). Excel is great and easy to use with tabular data - instead of having 9 separate ranges, you could have one block with an additional column containing the number of the episode for example. That simple change would improve readability and code significantly.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback again. The sheet is actually produced by a program, hence some of the mess, but I get what you mean about offsetting a selection rather than using the ranges. The current method is so close, but if I can't get it to work completely I will use the approach suggested. In that case I will msg to ask you put that as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks again for looking into this, again. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I would post this as a comment if I could but this is too long. So here it is as a query /potential solution*

I think your range references are the issue

The code below is a cut-down version of your code

`curr_ep` is a named range of *episode1*. It has a range address of `$Y$4:$AQ$58`

When you loop through the `a` variant you are setting a range with this syntax
`a = curr_ep.Range(curr_ep.Cells(n - 3, 1), curr_ep.Cells(n - 3, 11))`
which is equivalent to
`a = curr_ep.Range("Y2:AQ2")`

which means you are actually looking at **`AW2:BG2`** not `Y2:AQ2` which is what I think you may have intended, i.e. you are building in an unintended offset

```
Sub PopulateMedia()
    n = 1
    r = 1
    Dim curr_ep As Range
    Dim curr_test As Range
    Set curr_ep = Sheets(1).Range("episode" & r)
    Set curr_test = curr_ep.Range(curr_ep.Cells(n - 3, 1), curr_ep.Cells(n - 3, 11))
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't know how to cycle through code line-by-line e.g. get the yellow bar above, you should follow the follow the advice here on analyzing macros (http://www.excel4business.com/videos/analyzing-macros-error-handling.php). Basically if you introduce a break point on e.g. "Next n" then you can evaluate the various variables/components when the code exits the r loop

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I did step through the code in that way, but did not know how to check the address of the range variables as the above answer shows. I think the above answer has cracked it: the loop counters are working correctly as the debug showed, but copying from the wrong episode. Thanks for the link, I will view that now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I checked the original by making a a range and watching its address in debugging as shown, and the offset is exactly what is happening. I thought the line setting curr_test in your example would be selecting the 1st through 11th columns from (three rows up from the...) nth row of the current episode. Now that the problem is clear I will look for what is introducing that offset. Thank you very much indeed for the help and @assylias for the alternative solution.

Comment: Okay I understand now what was meant by the syntax used for declaring range 'a' causing the offset. Changing that line to a = Sheets(1).Range(curr_epCells(n, 5), curr_ep.Cells(n, 16)) solves the problem, and the macro now works as planned. I cannot thank enough for your help with these problems, this took me two full days and would have taken a lot more but for the help provided. Gratitude. Lots of it.